# Django Forms:Post request is got but data is not saved

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So I'm trying to build a Django site that collects Mod Applications to learn Django Forms. Except that I'm an idiot and I don't know what am I doing.
The thing that I'm trying to do is collect and save the Form data the current part and later try to show that data in the Django Admin the part I still haven't done and don't know how.

When I fill out the form I get `[06/May/2017 19:38:29] "POST /modapp HTTP/1.1" 200 2354`

This is my forms.py:

```
class Application(forms.ModelForm):



class Meta:
    model = ModApplication
    fields = ('discord', 'reddit', 'serverrank','finds','serverstay','active','timezone','reason','helped','help')


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Application, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['discord'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'UnknownDeveloper#2068'
    self.fields['reddit'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = '/u/UnknownDeveloper'
    self.fields['serverrank'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'GEOCACHING + RANK'
    self.fields['serverstay'].label = "How long have you been on the server"
    self.fields['active'].label = "How active have you been on the server"
    self.fields['timezone'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'CET'
    self.fields['reason'].label =  "Why do you want to become a mod?"
    self.fields['helped'].label =  "How have you helped the server so far?"
    self.fields['help'].label =  "How will you help the server if you'll become a mod"
```

models.py

```
class ModApplication(models.Model):
def __unicode__(self):
    return "Discord User: " + self.discord  + " aka " + self.reddit

reddit = models.CharField("Reddit Username", max_length=30)
discord = models.CharField("Discord Username", max_length=30)
serverrank = models.CharField("Server Rank", max_length=60)
finds  = models.CharField("Finds", max_length=12)
serverstay = models.CharField("Stayed on the server for",max_length=200)
active = models.CharField("Is Actice on Discord for", max_length=500)
timezone = models.CharField("Timezone", max_length=20)
reason = models.TextField("He likes to become a mod because", max_length=5000)
helped = models.TextField("He helped by", max_length=5000)
help = models.TextField("He'll help by", max_length=5000)
```

views.py

```
def formtofill(request):
form = Application() 
return render(request, 'appmod.html', {'form': form,})
if request.method == "POST":
    form = Application(request.POST)
    print(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        user.discord = request.discord
        user.reddit = request.reddit
        user.serverrank = request.serverrank
        user.finds = request.finds
        user.serverstay = request.serverstay
        user.active = request.active
        user.timezone = request.timezone
        user.reason = request.reason
        user.helped = request.helped
        user.help = request.help
        user.save()
        print(user)
        messages.success(request, 'Your Mod Application has been successfully submitted!')
        print(form)
        return HttpResponse('Successful')
else:
   form_class = Application
```

I searched a lot but I didn't find anything. I tried to print debug messages but they didn't print anything. I put the messages module but nothing happened. HTTPResponse just reloads back to the form. Help will be gladly accepted. Thanks for your time. If I am missing something please tell me and i'll edit my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a suprise that this code runs at all, it should be producing attribute errors for these:

```
    user.discord = request.discord
    user.reddit = request.reddit
```

But the reason that it doesn't is because the execution path never reaches that point

```
def formtofill(request):
   form = Application() 
   return render(request, 'appmod.html', {'form': form,})
```

Because of that return statement.

Your corrected code should look like

```
def formtofill(request):

    form = Application() 

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Application(request.POST)
        print(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your Mod Application has been successfully submitted!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success_url')
    else:
       form_class = Application
    return render(request, 'appmod.html', {'form': form,})
```

Comment: Yes. It works!! Thank you very much sorry I'm an idiot for Django

Answer (score 1):

Dont save the form upfront. Save but put commit=false.
Also remove that return statement as in the answer above mine.

```
user = form.save(commit=False).
```

Then an instance is created, but its not written into the database. Now you can do the assignments.

```
    user = form.save(commit=False).
    #Now....
    user.discord = request.POST['discord']
    user.reddit = request.POST['reddit']
    user.serverrank = request.POST['serverrank']
    user.finds = request.POST['finds']
    user.serverstay = request.POST['serverstay']
    ....................
    user.save()
    return HttpResponse('Successful')
```

Instead you were trying to access the data as an attribute of the request object itself. The form data are contained in request.POST, then you have to access it from there.

Also,

```
else:
    form = Application()
```

You need to instantiate the form class.

Comment: sorry but it's wrong to get data from request.POST. you need to get data from form.cleaned_data

Comment: Yeah.. that's right. I wasn't saying it's the right way, but I was saying it could also be done. Thanks for the heads up.. I'll keep it in mind from now on.